# Cordova-android how to edit the project.properties file generated when adding a platform

Tags: android, cordova

So when adding my android platform using `cordova add platform android` the folder that it generates creates a `project.properties` file.

This file (in my project) has the following line:

```
cordova.system.library.15=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+
```

Now due to a new release (`1.4` beta) this causes my build to fail.

So I would like to edit this file and add a specific version number.

However since I am using a build server I really want this to happen as soon as I run the command `cordova platform add android`

Where can I change these settings?